# Using the .NET Framework ArrayList Class - How to find methods

Tags: powershell, .net-framework

How can I find what methods and properties the ArrayList class has?

I am a junior sys-admin, teaching myself Powershell. I know about coding, what a dog knows about a clock.
In Powershell I can pipe a variable or command to the `Get-Member` cmdlet, and this will list all the methods, and properties available to me.
However, if I do this:
`$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`
`$a | gm`

I get the following:
`gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet....`

I am going through the Technet Powershell Tip of the week guides, and they show a couple methods, such as `Remove` and `RemoveRange`.
How can I find all the methods associated with a .NET class, with Powershell? Is this available, or do I need to look elsewhere? Would I have to do a Google search, every time I want to use the various methods?

I guess I'm saying, teach me to fish.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for your case:

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
```

Reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/09/using-powershell-get-member-to-explore-the-net-framework.aspx

Comment: Whoops, I covered the long approach to Get-Member, calling reflections itself. So +1 for reminding me of the short hand!

Comment: @Patrick Smashing. Thanks for the link. This is what I needed. It's maddening, for me, that `$a | gm` doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure why the pipeline method doesn't work, but indeed it doesn't. Maybe because, when the ArrayList is created, it's still empty/null? I'm sure someone knows the answer to why, but it's not me. :)

Answer (score 2):

From Get-Member help:

> -- When you pipe a collection of objects to Get-Member, Get-Member gets the members of the individual objects
>   in the collection, such as the properties of each string in an array of strings.
>
> -- When you use InputObject to submit a collection of objects, Get-Member gets the members of the collection,
>   such as the properties of the array in an array of strings.

So, you can use the following to get the members from your ArrayList object:

```
,$a | gm
```

This works because you are passing Get-Member an array of ArrayList objects (only one in this case). If you just pass the ArrayList, Get-Member will try to run on the members of the ArrayList, which is empty, thus the error.

This is a little more obvious when the ArrayList has some members, as in the following:

```
$a = [System.Collections.ArrayList](1..3)
$a | gm
```

which returns

```
   TypeName: System.Int32

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(int value), int IComparable.CompareTo(Syste...
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(int obj), bool IEquatable[int].Equals(int other)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

PowerShell is pretty awesome with arays out off the box, without using the explicit ArrayList.

```
$myArray = @()
$myArray += "Sam"
$myArray += "Tom"
```

Or you can do

```
$myArray = @("Sam", "Tom", "John")
```

To remove an item, we can do some fun things too.

```
$myArray = $myArray | ? {$_ -ne "Sam"}
```

But, if all you really want is to get a list of the methods and properties, you can use reflection (A .NET class) to extract that information, like so:

```
 [reflection.assembly]::GetAssembly("System.Collections.ArrayList") | Get-Member
```

Or **only** the names of the methods and types

```
[reflection.assembly]::GetAssembly("System.Collections.ArrayList") | Get-Member | Select Name, MemberType
```

That will get you:

```
Name                 MemberType
----                 ----------
ModuleResolve             Event
CreateInstance           Method
Equals                   Method
GetCustomAttributes      Method
GetCustomAttributesData  Method
GetExportedTypes         Method
GetFile                  Method
GetFiles                 Method
GetHashCode              Method
GetInterface             Method
GetLoadedModules         Method
GetManifestResourceInfo  Method
GetManifestResourceNames Method
GetManifestResourceStreamMethod
GetModule                Method
GetModules               Method
GetName                  Method
GetObjectData            Method
GetReferencedAssemblies  Method
GetSatelliteAssembly     Method
GetType                  Method
GetTypes                 Method
IsDefined                Method
LoadModule               Method
ToString                 Method
CodeBase               Property
EntryPoint             Property
EscapedCodeBase        Property
Evidence               Property
FullName               Property
GlobalAssemblyCache    Property
HostContext            Property
ImageRuntimeVersion    Property
IsDynamic              Property
IsFullyTrusted         Property
Location               Property
ManifestModule         Property
PermissionSet          Property
ReflectionOnly         Property
SecurityRuleSet        Property
```

Or, as @PatrickS. mentioned, there is a PowerShell command to skip calling the Reflection class:

```
"System.Collections.ArrayList" | Get-Member
```

Comment: I had, erroneously, tried `Systems.Collections.ArrayList | Get-Member` without the quotes. Thank you for adding that.